# Anything like, "foreach (Row x in table.Rows)", but for Calendar control days?

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, calendar, web-controls

We have a ASP.Net Calendar control, and in the DayRender event, we have the following code:

```
protected void calminical1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox mycb = new CheckBox();
    e.Cell.Controls.Add(mycb);
}
```

This makes every day in the Calendar contain a CheckBox.  The purpose and idea behind this is, an employee can apply for vacation time by simply selecting the days visually in the calendar that he/she wants off.

Problem is, I don't know how to loop through the calendar to find out what days the user has checked.

For GridViews, I often use:

```
foreach (Row x in table.Rows)
{
   //loop through all rows
}
```

Essentially I need to do the same thing, but for "cells" or "days" of the Calendar control.  Most of these web controls have collections that are obvious and intuitive, i.e. dropdown list and other list controls have "Items", tables and gridviews have "Rows", but I can't seem to find the equivalent for Calendar controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code I ended up using to achieve what I was looking for.  Maybe someone else will find it useful:

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddToDates(Calendar1.SelectedDate);
}

private void AddToDates(DateTime newDate)
{
    DateTime selecteddate;
    ArrayList datelist;
    if (ViewState["SelectedDates"] != null)
    {
        datelist = (ArrayList)ViewState["SelectedDates"];
        for (int x = 0; x < datelist.Count; x++)
        {
            selecteddate = (DateTime)datelist[x];
            Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(selecteddate);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        datelist = new ArrayList();
    }
    if (datelist.Contains(newDate))
    {
        Calendar1.SelectedDates.Remove(newDate);
        datelist.Remove(newDate);
    }
    else
    {
        Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(newDate);
        datelist.Add(newDate);
    }

    ViewState["SelectedDates"] = datelist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use some kind of datastructure to save the state of your application and not the calendar itself.

you could register the DateSelected-Event to capture the selected dates and save it. after that you could loop through your saved dates.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

in Javascript create a array on your aspx page

var dates=new Array();

```
Sub ca_DayRender(sender As Object, e As DayRenderEventArgs)
   Dim d as CalendarDay
   Dim c as TableCell
   Dim datOrigin as Date = "1-1-2000"
   Dim strDayNum as String
   d = e.Day
   c = e.Cell
   strDayNum = CStr(DateDiff("d", datOrigin, d.date))
   If d.IsOtherMonth Then
     c.Controls.Clear
   Else
     c.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "dates.push(strDayNum);)
   End If
 End Sub
```

Then you can access the array through a post back when ever you need the values using

"javascript:__doPostBack('ca','" & strDayNum & "')"